# Prevent default behavior of Ipad browser when a textbox was focused

Tags: css

I have a problem on Ipad 4. Because a client requests that when the text box from a light box wax clicked/focused and when the keyboard pops, the lightbox was pushed up that the, how can I prevent it on IPAD?

Comment: I have a problem on Ipad 4. Because a client requests that when the text box from a light box wax clicked/focused and when the keyboard pops, the lightbox was pushed up that the content, how can I prevent it on IPAD?

Comment: I'll appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: not sure what are you looking for but maybe `readonly="true"`?

Comment: I want to prevent safari from scrolling the window when a text box has focus.